# Which font is used in this Warranty Rewards logo?

Tags: font-identification

[image: Warranty Rewards logo]

I’m having a hard time identifying this serif typeface used for *Rewards* in the above logo a client presented to me. They also have no recollection to what the name of the typeface is.

I’ve tried multiple resources including *What The Font* and my own collection of typefaces. But no luck. The closest I can relate the typeface to is [Fairplay Display](https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse) because of the ear on the letter *r.* But besides that, all that I can tell is that *Rewards* contains both a serif and sans-Serif collection of faces, due to the letters *a* and *e* being san-serif like.

I can also assume that this is a really bad script typeface found on Font Squirrel. But, I couldn’t find anything there either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is Century Schoolbook Bold Italic (mine's just distorted cause I didn't scale proportionally)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try New Century Schoolbook Bold Italic with -40 tracking - Very close
a little bit of fiddling with kerning and no body will know the difference!

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)